# Constantly getting bad json response from parse.com servers when saving files

Tags: android, parse-platform

i am getting bad json resonse exception when saving files to parse.com
I load a file from device then convert it into byte array then store it. Have no idea about the exception, parse throws this exception which i have added here.

This only happens when trying to upload pdf file. Or don't know with some particular files maybe. Rest are doing just fine.

```
InputStream is = null;
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        is = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uris[0]);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        byte[] data = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        ParseFile parseFile = new ParseFile("FILE.pdf",data);

        parseFile.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                         if(e!=null) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                         }
                    }
         });
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Logger.Log("FileLoaderTask", "FileNotFound");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.Log("FileLoaderTask", "Couldn't read file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (is != null) try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is my stack trace.

```
07-31 18:49:11.890  31041-31041/in.co.unilive.unilive W/System.err﹕ com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: bad json response
07-31 18:49:11.890  31041-31041/in.co.unilive.unilive W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseRequest.newTemporaryException(ParseRequest.java:372)
07-31 18:49:11.890  31041-31041/in.co.unilive.unilive W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseRESTCommand.onResponseAsync(ParseRESTCommand.java:265)
07-31 18:49:11.900  31041-31041/in.co.unilive.unilive W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:188)
07-31 18:49:11.900  31041-31041/in.co.unilive.unilive W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:184)
07-31 18:49:11.900  31041-31041/in.co.unilive.unilive W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
07-31 18:49:11.900  31041-31041/in.co.unilive.unilive W/System.err﹕ at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
07-31 18:49:11.900  31041-31041/in.co.unilive.unilive W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:787)
07-31 18:49:11.910  31041-31041/in.co.unilive.unilive W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:599)
07-31 18:49:11.910  31041-31041/in.co.unilive.unilive W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:610)
07-31 18:49:11.910  31041-31041/in.co.unilive.unilive W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:702)
07-31 18:49:11.920  31041-31041/in.co.unilive.unilive W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:690)
07-31 18:49:11.920  31041-31041/in.co.unilive.unilive W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
07-31 18:49:11.920  31041-31041/in.co.unilive.unilive W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-31 18:49:11.920  31041-31041/in.co.unilive.unilive W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-31 18:49:11.930  31041-31041/in.co.unilive.unilive W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-31 18:49:11.930  31041-31041/in.co.unilive.unilive W/System.err﹕ Caused by: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
07-31 18:49:11.930  31041-31041/in.co.unilive.unilive W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
07-31 18:49:11.940  31041-31041/in.co.unilive.unilive W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
07-31 18:49:11.940  31041-31041/in.co.unilive.unilive W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:155)
07-31 18:49:11.940  31041-31041/in.co.unilive.unilive W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
07-31 18:49:11.940  31041-31041/in.co.unilive.unilive W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseRESTCommand.onResponseAsync(ParseRESTCommand.java:255)
07-31 18:49:11.950  31041-31041/in.co.unilive.unilive W/System.err﹕ ... 13 more
```

Comment: also add some code and some json response

Comment: @mukul, what do you want to do with parse, i had the same issue..so tell me , what do you want to do with parse??

Comment: @TheGreat004 This happen when m uploading a file to parse.

Comment: and u are uploading file with rest.....am i right??

Comment: No. with android sdk

Comment: post your code buddy..as i had done it with rest api of parse

Comment: Do you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

**Check for out of date library references!**

Using Android Studio I was using `compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'` which started giving me "Bad json response" issues when logging a user in.
Changing the parse library to `compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.12` fixed this response for me.